# POST Request external in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to registering data from mobile app to the server laravel.

Only a 500 error occurs when performed via Ajax post.

Below is how I am using.

route:

```
Route::post('sendmobile', function() {

   echo serialize(Input::get('json')); 

});
```

App mobile:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "http://host/sendmobile/",
                data: { name:'Marcelo', number:'11' },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(){
                   alert("Success!");
                   return true;
                },

                complete: function() {
            alert('Finish');
                },

                error: function() {
                  alert('faild');
                  return false;
                }
             });
```

Tks.

Comment: Execute the code in a browser and enable debugging aid. Step through the code and inspect, what URL actually gets called.

Comment: thanks for listening ..
Below is what happens in the debug    --------HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: Identity
Content-Type: text/html
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.10
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8x DAV/2 PHP/5.4.10
Date: Sun, 25 Aug 2013 19:32:08 GMT

Comment: Resolved!!
 
The laravel does not working with final bar end "/".

    url: "http://host/sendmobile/" to url: "http://host/sendmobile"

Thks